# If is toBlockingFirst method reliable?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java2

My question about the method `toBlockingFirst()`.

Is it a reliable method? i.e. Can I get `InterruptedException` with crash

if I call dispose for disposable from subscrine?

for example:

```
.flatMap{ host ->
    val count = userRepository.getUsers(PrefProvider.currentTourCode)
        .map { it.size }
        .blockingFirst()
    if (count>2) {
        callSomething()
    } else {
        callElse()
    } 
}
```

Can someone to explain me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `flatMap` runs on an RxJava `Scheduler` the time `blockingFirst` is invoked, you'll likely get an `InterruptedException` wrapped into a `RuntimeException`. However, you should not call blocking methods in a handler but compose via `flatMap`

```
.flatMap{ host ->
    userRepository.getUsers(PrefProvider.currentTourCode)
        .flatMap { 
            if (it.size) {
               return callSomething()
            }
            return callElse()
        }
 }
```

Depending on what `callSomething` and `callElse` are supposed to do and if they should return something, you could also have `map` `doOnNext` instead of `flatMap` in there.

Comment: It is good idea. So now think i can realy to avoid using toBlocking for this moment thanks